# Unnesting results of function returning multiple values in summarize

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

The "wanted" result is given by the "do" function below. I thought that I could get the same with some use of unnest, but could not get it to work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Function rr is given
rr = function(x){
  # This should be an expensive and possibly random function
  r = range(x + rnorm(length(x),0.1))
#  setNames(r, c("min", "max")) # fails, expecting single value
#  list(min = r[1], max= r[2]) # fails
  list(r) # Works, but result is in "long" form without min/max
}

# Works, but syntactically awkward
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  do( {
    r = rr(.$Sepal.Width)[[1]]
    data_frame(min = r[1], max = r[2])
  })

# This give the long format, but without column
# names min/max
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(
    range = rr(Sepal.Length)
  ) %>% unnest(range)
```

Comment: @Bulat: The example above is perfectly reproducible. Furthermore, it is stripped down of all unnecessary clutter. Hence I do not understand your comment.

Comment: I was not aware of iris data set, i guess what is missing is the desired result or details on what is not working. you provided two examples of working code, it is not clear what is wrong.

Comment: The first example is simply not elegant code, even if the result is right. Run the second one to see what is different.

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution for this problem currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Unnest()` will always unlist your nested columns in a "long" format, but you could use `spread()` to get the desired output if you create a `key` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(range = rr(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  unnest(range) %>% mutate(newcols = rep(c("min", "max"), 3)) %>%
  spread(newcols, range)
#     Species      max      min
#      (fctr)    (dbl)    (dbl)
#1     setosa 7.636698 3.292692
#2 versicolor 9.792319 3.337382
#3  virginica 9.810723 3.367066
```

Comment: Not elegant, but a solution which I will tick later because it confirms that  unnest alone does not do it.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a pretty straight forward alternative using the `data.table` package

```
# Function rr is given
rr = function(x) as.list(setNames(range(x + rnorm(length(x), 0.1)), c("min", "max"))) 

library(data.table)
data.table(iris)[, rr(Sepal.Width), by = Species]
#       Species      min      max
# 1:     setosa 1.839845 6.341040
# 2: versicolor 1.063727 5.498810
# 3:  virginica 1.232525 5.402483
```

Comment: With your definition of `rr`, it's also possible use `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(data.frame(rr(.$Sepal.Length)))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus, yeah, but both `data.frame` (by group) and `do` are somewhat inefficient, hence, I prefer avoiding them. I would guess `spread` and `unneset` are pretty inefficient too (but haven't checked it). `as.list` should be efficient IMO.

Comment: Well I was not suggesting it would be more efficient than your data.table approach. It just seemed worth mentioning since his Q is specifically about dplyr and tagged with dplyr

Comment: @docendodiscimus Ok, that make sense. You can edit, or post or leave it as is- it's up to you.

Comment: Interesting and concise, but efficiency for me is not so relevant. And I admit, that years ago I once was bitten by incorrectly using the special syntax of data.table.

Comment: data_frame instead of data.frame is much more efficient (even if it is not relevant for my case).

Comment: @docendo discimus: My favorite in combination with David's rr, after Hadley confirmed there was no easier solution.

Comment: Appologies for not testing: data_frame does not work here, must use data.frame.